# How do I modify the status code in a HTTP response in swagger

Tags: swagger

I have a swagger .yaml file and I am using codegen to create a spring boot application.How can I modify the HTTP response in swagger.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that codegen does not work as you said. This app generates a simple code. I advice you to use the following generator for Spring Boot (named as "Spring MVC"):

https://github.com/BBVA-CIB/APIRestGenerator